# Compute $Pr[Geo(1/8) < Geo(1/4) ]$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $A \sim Geo(1/8)$ and $A \sim Geo(1/4)$ be two independent variables. Compute $Pr(A<B)$.

Attempt:

Let $Z = A-B$. We seek $$P(Z>0)= \sum_{z=1}^{\infty} P(Z=z).$$
And $$P(Z=z) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} P(A=k) P (B=k-z)$$ But I'm not sure if a double summation is correct here.

---

New attempt:

$$P(A<B) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(A=n)  \cdot  P(B \ge n+1)$$

we calculate each product by itself

$$P(A = n) = (1/4) (1-1/4)^n$$

and

$$P(B \ge n+1) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(B = n+1) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1/4) (1-1/4)^{(n+1)-1} = 4/3$$

so we combine and get

$$P(A<B) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1/4) (1-1/4)^n \cdot (4/3). $$

Comment: Independence here? Add that information to your question.

Comment: Yes they are. Added now.

Comment: typo: one of the first two $A$'s must become a $B$. Can the geometrics take value $0$ here? (counting of failures)

Comment: Rather use $$P(A<B)=\sum_nP(A=n)P(B\geqslant n+1),$$ which simply requires the evaluation of two geometric series successively.

Comment: Can I use $P(B=n+1)$ instead? I don't have the pdf for $P (B \ge n+1)$ Or should I run $P (B \ge n+1) = \sum P(B = n+1)$ for some chosen start and end point?

Comment: You could use P(B=n+1) instead of P(B>=n+1) but then the result would be false. This is up to you.

Comment: I ran the second options, and updated my post after this. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Do you seriously believe that P(B >= n+1) does not depend on n?

Comment: Where in my attempt have I stated that?

Comment: Quote: "P(B≥n+1)=∑P(B=n+1) –  jacob Sep 16 at 11:10". Other quote (under "New attempt"): "$P(B \ge n+1) = ... = 16/3$" (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: @Did I updated my attempt but am I still wrong regarding  $$P(B \ge n+1) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(B = n+1) \; ?$$

Comment: The sum on the RHS of the identity in your last comment is equal to ... ?